# IE11 - Login button/submission buttons not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer-11

I am having an issue with my website. With the release of IE11, our login button on our login page simply doesn't work anymore.

Comment: update your question with the html code for buttons/form

Answer (score 1):

check if you submit button has the attribute `name`, if not try to adding it to your submit button.

```
<input type="button" name="MyButton" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

I hope it can help you. I think it is a problem of HTML with IE 11 and is not exclusive of Rails.

Comment: This has been really annoying me all day! You're a star!